# Can't find font for the newspaper "Le Temps"

Tags: fonts, typography, logo, font-identification, typefaces

I need to identify the logo font for "Le Temps", a swiss newspaper. It is similar to a times-like font, but not exactly sure. Whatthefont doesn't help me...gives me over 60 matches.

[image: Le Temps]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WhatTheFont gave me two:

http://bit.ly/LeTemps-LogoFont

**Modern Two Sixtn Medium** is what you're looking for I think.

Comment: @alisamii, if that's not quite right, you might try http://typophile.com/typeid to find an answer there.